# Regex to match only if beginning of line isn't something?

Tags: vim, regex, sublime-text-2

I have some lines that I'd like to match and some lines I'd to exclude from matching in a file.

I'd like to not match `remote access</a> (main card)` and would like to match `anything else</a> (main card)`

I'm not quite sure how to tell it "if it has this, DON'T MATCH!"

I'm using sublime text 2 now, but can switch to vim or similar if it makes it easier.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?!remote access)[^<]*</a> \(main card\)
```

Comment: This wasn't working for me for some reason, but then I realized it was set to "selection only" in sublime text. This'll get me off to a great start on fixing up some files!

Comment: AAAAND I got everything where it needed to be all at once! This was a huge jumpstart onto what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

In Vim, you can use the `\@<!` regular expression atom to assert that the atom before it does **not** match. In your example, that would be:

```
/\%(remote access\)\@<!<\/a> (main card)
```